# How to smooth my accelerometer-based character movement in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I am building an infinite vertical platformer for mobile platforms and I am using the accelerometer to move the player left and right. The further the device is tilted the faster the player moves across the screen. Currently my player is a little too shakey and I would like to create a more fluid movement across the screen. Here is my code to move the character:

```
  /********************************* Variables  **************************************/

        // Variables
        float jumpForce = 700f;
        float maxSpeed;
        float acceleration;

  /********************************* Start Method ************************************/

        void Start ()
            {
            acceleration = Mathf.Abs (Input.acceleration.y);
            }

  /************************************ Fixed Update  *************************************/

        void FixedUpdate () {

                if (acceleration < 0.2f) {
                    maxSpeed = 17;
                } else if (acceleration < 0.9f) {
                    maxSpeed = 25;
                } else {
                    maxSpeed = 40;
                }

            float move = Input.acceleration.x;
                rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    /******************************* Collision Function ******************************/

        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
            {
                foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in coll.contacts)
                {   
                     rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use your `Input.acceleration.y` as the speed? That way you wont need the if conditions. If that's not enough, then multiply it by a multiplier.

```
void Update () {
    maxSpeed = Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.y);
    speedMultiplier = 30;

    float move = Input.acceleration.x;
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed * speedMultiplier, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
```

You can just adjust the `speedMultiplier` to match your needs afterwards.
Also if you have some physics works (in this case `rigidbody2D.velocity`), you should use `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: This might be helpful, but it doesn't actually smooth the accelerometer input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathf.Lerp method for smoothing the velocity values.

Try to use

`maxSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(maxSpeed, 17, Time.deltaTime);`

instead of

`maxSpeed = 17;`